# PromQL - by-namespace with a calculation

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, metrics, promql, thanos

Getting CPU usage percentage in prometheus requires a calculation of CPU seconds divided by number of CPUs (or requests, etc, whatever way you're doing it).

If you want something by namespace, you have to do something like:

```
count by (namespace)(metric_name{kubernetes_cluster="$cluster"})
```

How can you make a division while doing something by namespace though?  I don't believe this works as is, but this is roughly what I'm looking to achieve.

```
count by (namespace)(metric_one{kubernetes_cluster="$cluster"}) /
count by (namespace)(metric_two{kubernetes_cluster="$cluster"})
```

I would need the namespaces on those metrics to be in sync as the division happens, and I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

The provided last query should work as expected, e.g. Prometheus should find pairs of time series with identical `namespace` label on both sides of `/` and perform individual division per each of such pair. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators) for details.